# Android java horizontal list

Tags: java, android

When swiping a horizontal list made via recyclerview, you can scroll through several items. Is it possible to make it so that only 1 element can be scrolled when swiping? And if you can't use recyclerview, are there any ready-made libraries for this?

Comment: Did you try using `viewpager` ? I guess that would be good for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways but [PagerSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/PagerSnapHelper) would be the easiest.

```
RecyclerView recyclerview = (RecyclerView) 
findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_horizontal);
SnapHelper mSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
mSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerview);
```